# Exit price during backtest in tradingview doesn't take the correct value

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to backtest the below script in tradingview:

```
strategy("my startegy", overlay=true)
smma(src, length) =>
    smma=0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
jawLength = input(13, "Jaw Length")
jawOffset = input(8, "Jaw Offset")
jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)
val1=close
val2=close
close1=close
close2=close

longCondition = crossover(close, jaw)

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry(id="buy", long=true, limit=close)
    val1:=close-low
    close1=close

shortCondition = crossunder(close, jaw)

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry(id="sell", long=false, limit=close)
    val2:=close-low
    close2=close

strategy.exit(id="exit1", from_entry="buy", when=(close>=(close1+val1)or close<=(close1)))
strategy.exit(id="exit2", from_entry="sell", when=(close<=(close2-val2)or close>=(close2)))
```

The above code gives the takes the correct value for the buy/sell entry price but when exiting it takes some random values during the backseat.

I am trying to exit the trade as follows:

1. if it's a long trade-> exit the stock when the price reaches `(close price at the time of entry) plus (difference of high and low at the time of entry)` OR `when the stock hits SL, which should be the low at the time of entry`.
2. Similarly, if it's a short trade -> exit when price reaches `(close price at the time of entry) minus (difference of high and low at the time of entry)` OR `when the stock hits SL, which should be the high at the time of entry`.

Now let's take for example the below chart for Apple:

[image]

It shows a buy entry on 22-apr-2020 at 19:15 for the price of 273.51 (when the crossover happened) which is correct but the SL was set at 273.3 and it should have been triggered in the next candle because the next candle has a low of 273.11. However the backtest trade gives a sell signal on 23-apr-2020 at 23:00    for the price of 277.43

Comment: 1) You don't specify PIne version of your script. Assume that is v4 2) If you try to compile 
your script the pine compiler gives some warnings https://i.imgur.com/WJCN20M.png about wrong usage of `strategy.exit` I.e. the strategy.exit doesn't exit never. Your strategy is reversal strategy.

Comment: @AndreyD Thanks for your reply. I am using version 4. I have modified the code. Please check if you get any errors. Actually what I want is the stoploss and profit to be calculated based on the difference between high and low of the candle when the trade took place. So for example, if I buy at a price of 100 and the high and low on that particular candle are 110 and 90 resp., my stop-loss should be 100 - (110-90)= 80 and profit = 100 + (110-90) = 120

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm not see any changes in the code above ... If you have appropriate take profit & stop loss price levels you can specify it like this: `strategy.exit(..., limit = profitPriceLevel, stop = stoplossPriceLevel)`